# Laravel Migration Error Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration, cascade, laravel-9

This is the error showing every time.

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `codehacking`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  1   G:\Laravel\CodeHacking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `codehacking`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"))
  2   G:\Laravel\CodeHacking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

users table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('is_active')->default(0);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

posts table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('photo_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

I am having this error every time I try to migrate my table. How to solve it.?
This code is based on laravel-9. I am trying to create tables with the php aritsan migrate command every time I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('photo_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: For answers, please include a short description of what you changed and how it solved your issue. A code dump is considered low-quality, and may be downvoted and/or removed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too . This error will handle when foreign key type and its reference type are not match . For example , if foreign key type is (int) but reference key type is (biginteger) this error will handle.

Comment: foreign key type and its references must be the same.